# Loop through chisq.test RStudio

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, survey

I am trying to perform chisquare tests on about 30 variables. I tried to write a for loop to no luck. The loop should also save the p-value of each test.

I have used this kind of setup before, in other instances, but I recognise that using a vector with the dataframe$variable names does not work on this occasion. I suspect that there is something fundamental I do not understand about the translation from text to variable name.

Example:

```
survey <- data.frame(
  sex = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1),
  health = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5),
  happiness = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5)
)

variables <- c("survey$health", "data$happiness")
nLoops <- length(variables)

result <- matrix(nrow = nLoops, ncol = 2)

for (i in 1:nLoops){
  test <- chisq.test(variables[i], survey$sex)
  result[, 1] <- test$data.name
  result[, 2] <- test$p.value
}
```

Comment: First of all, this gets borderline to StackOverflow I think, but anyways, can you maybe clarify the goal of your analysis? Is it correct you want to test if sex and health and sex and happiness are independent? Either way, as the error says in your R console, the problem is in the fact that you run a Chi-squared test on the 'variables[i]', which is the string "survey$health", if you can confirm the goal of your analysis, I will provide a working code in the answers!

Comment: This is bound for stackoverflow. But you need to ask them a better question as well. It helps to show what you got and what you want. I can see straight away you forgot to index the last two assignment steps correctly. It should be `result[i, 1] <- test$data.name`. For variables, just set `<- c('health', 'happiness')`. And then it is `survey[,variables[i]]` to get the data.